# Visual C++ 2008 64-bit compiler?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, 64-bit

I've noticed that when I compile a 64-bit program from Visual Studio 2008, the compiler that runs is in the `bin\x86_amd64` folder, not from the `bin\amd64` folder -- even though both of them exist.

Is there any way to force the 64-bit compiler to run instead of the cross-compiler?

Comment: May I ask why do you care which compiler creates the 64-bit executable? The final result is the same, isn't it?

Comment: @eran: I'm hoping the 64-bit version might be faster. And I feel it's a little pointless for it to be on the computer otherwise...

Comment: what do you think will be faster? the compiler or the executable created?

Comment: @stijn: The compiler, obviously.

Comment: 64-bit compiler cannot be faster, but might be slower :-). AFAIR dynamic_cast in 64-bit code is few times slower than in 32-bit code

Comment: well definitely let us know if it really is.. I just tested it on a couple of small projects (build time about 20 seconds) and there was no difference whatsoever. Makse me wonder why MS ships both of them though, so +1 for your question

Comment: @Jurlie: source for that statement?

Comment: @stijn: Nah, I didn't see a difference, either. :( It was worth the try, though. :)

Comment: @stijn: cannot provide: that information was from my teammate who had being optimizing some heavy 3D-algorythm. Anyway I should try to check it myself :-)

Comment: @eran FYI, the #import directive will not see a 64-bit COM server when compiled from a cross-compiler (i.e. 32-bit cl.exe). According to [MSDN for #import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6(v=VS.100).aspx): *"Note that when compiling with a cross compiler on a 64-bit operating system, the compiler will be able to read only the 32-bit registry hive. You might want to use the native 64-bit compiler to build and register a 64-bit type library."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go to `Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->VC++ Directories`, then select `x64` for platform and select `Executable Files`. This list is like a PATH environment variable for everything started from within VS, including compiler/linker/debugger etc.

Normally the first line will be

```
$(VCInstallDir)bin\x86_amd64
```

so changing this to

```
 $(VCInstallDir)bin\amd64
```

will pick cl.exe etc from that directory instead.

Comment: Ahhhhh that's **exactly** what I was looking for, thanks a bunch! It helps with a lot of other things as well. :)

Comment: yeah it's a great feature - I even used it to run the VS2010 compiler etc within VS2008 as I like it better.